# SignalR Server .net core Self Hosted

Tags: .net-core, server, signalr, background-service, self-hosting

How can I implement start and use SignalR in a BackgroundService without dependency injection in Program.cs? (self hosted)

I have a small service which eighter runs in **server** or **client** mode.

A *Worker.cs* implements BackgroundService and inits a *SmallService* instance. The worker is started in *Program.cs*

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .UseWindowsService(options => {
       options.ServiceName = "SomeService";
   }).ConfigureServices(
       (hostContext, services) => {
           services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
       }
   ).Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

I don't want to change both *Worker.cs* and *Program.cs*

Currently, when the `SmallService` starts in **Server-Mode** a class implements [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) Websocket client which can be used easily and straight forward ..

```
class WebSocket_Server {
  
  public WebSocket_Server() {
    server = new WebSocketServer($"ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
  }

  public void Connect() {

    server.Start(socket => {

        socket.OnOpen = async () => {
          await socket.emit("some message");
        };

        socket.onMessage = (data) => {
          ... do something with data
        }
   }
}
```

I wonder if I could replace Flecks Websocket with SignalR. I would like to use SingalR similar to Flecks. I just would like to start an use a SignalR server

But the only solutions i've found so far are

- The Depricated [SelfHosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) package which is not for core but looked good in the first place.
- The second option is calling `services.addSignalR()` in `Program.cs` explained in [Microsofts Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and MapHub to the resulting App.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapHub<ClockHub>("/hubs/clock");
app.Run();
```

That doesn't work for my `host` so I have to change the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` to some `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`?
Where is the difference between both? I'm not willing to change BackgroundService default Builder process to use a Server-Instance.